# hosted site missing elements from local html file

Tags: javascript, html, css, hosting, local

The website I am building is simple html,CSS and JavaScript. It works as intended in the local file (opening the html file in chrome). Once I host it however, It is missing strange small pieces.

example, in the center of my page I have a large div (400px tall) as specified in my CSS file. so I checked my CSS file to insure that it was hosted, it was. Not only that, but it was still defining other elements' CSS properties. somehow the hosted site was ignoring my div element. (see below)

```
    #map {
    height: 400px;  /* this is displayed */
    width: 70%; 
   }
   #myElement {  /* this is not */
    background: silver;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    font: 30px/300px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
```

example 2: I created a button to activate a function. This function worked fine on the local file, but seemingly dissapears on my hosted file. Same situation as before, the js file was performing its other jobs, just not this one. see below

```
    <button onclick="vibrateButton()">Vibrate</button>

    function vibrateButton() {
  navigator.vibrate([500]);
  console.log("vibrated")
}
```

error found in console :Uncaught ReferenceError: vibrateButton is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):73)

I tried saving everything again and re-uploading the site, same result. I am at a loss. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you havent included the script tag. include it and try

```html
<button onclick="vibrateButton()">Vibrate</button>
<script>
function vibrateButton() {
  navigator.vibrate([500]);
  console.log("vibrated")
}
</script>
```